# How to make responsive web and mobile application using react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to ReactNative so can anyone help me to make the design responsive for Desktop and Mobile View.

Answer (score 0):

In react native if you want to make responsive UI .You have to know

1. Layout With Flexbox
2. Aspect Ratio
3. Screen Dimensions
4. Detect the Platform
5. Device Screen Orientation